# Pushing to existing repository local changes with creating a new branch

Tags: git

I've just cleaned my disk and now I'm willing to go back to working on my project which I downloaded back from Gitlab. After I've downloaded and made few changes, I want to push it back on Gitlab with creating a new branch. What I've done so far is:

```
git init 
git remote add upstream https://gitlab.com/xxx/xxxxxxxxxx.git
git fetch upstream
```

after typing last command it gave me output of 3 branches:

- x
- y
- master

But now what I want to do is:

- create a new branch
- commit changes to a new branch
- push the branch to gitlab

How can I proceed with this?

Comment: This is fundamental Git stuff. Are you having trouble doing those things for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way of proceeding would be

```
# create the new branch from some reference branch (master, x or y, your call)
git checkout -b <branchName> <referenceBranch>

# now make your changes in the code until you're fine with it

# add and commit those changes
git add path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3
git commit -m "Useful message"

# push to gitlab with the -u option to set upstream
git push -u upstream <branchName>
```

See the part about setting upstream here in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u).

Comment: I've had some troubles yesterday with pushing. The funny thing is that, that I've realized today I forgot to run git config and I was too lazy to read errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a new branch and switch to it:

```
git checkout -b [branch name]
```

Commit changes to new branch (once you've made them):

```
git commit -a -m "Commit Message"
```

Push the branch to Gitlab:

```
git push --set-upstream [remote name] [branch name]
```